# Using jupyter notebook in Luakit (web browser)?

Tags: python, browser, jupyter-notebook

Officially, jupyter notebook supports Chrome, Safari and Firefox (see paragraph 1.9 [here](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/jupyter-notebook/latest/jupyter-notebook.pdf)). I'm trying to use it with the lightweight [Luakit browser](https://luakit.github.io/). My notebook opens correctly in Luakit, I can execute a cell by pressing the Run button in the task bar, but the keyboard isn't responsive from within the opened notebook window (the keyboard works elsewhere): I can't navigate, nor press `shift` + `enter` to execute a cell, nor even edit a cell.

Does any one know how to set up Luakit to be able to use it with jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 0):

I have just found a simple solution to be able to use the keyboard from within a jupyter notebook cell: go into **insert mode**, by typing `i` (letter i). Unless someone can provide guidelines so that there's no need to first type `i`, I'll take this approach as an answer.